# Где тут должны быть запятые и почему?

Tags: пунктуация

**Пойманные скворцы быстро привыкают к людям (1) и (2) если живут в доме (3) летают по комнатам (4) радуются своему хозяину доверчиво садятся ему на плечо.**

Подскажите, где тут должны быть запятые и почему. С учителем спорим, каждый при своем мнении.

Comment: Учитель не увидел бесспорную запятую? Пятую, самую очевидную?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Пойманные скворцы быстро привыкают к людям и, если живут в доме, летают по комнатам, радуются своему хозяину, доверчиво садятся ему на плечо.**

1-я запятая не нужна, т. к. однородные сказуемые соединены союзом *И*: *привыкают и летают,..*;
2-я и 3-я отделяют придаточное предложение;
4-я и 5-я (которую Вы забыли отметить) разделяют однородные сказуемые: *летают, радуются, садятся*.

Comment: Интуитивно согласен с расстановкой запятых, но все не так просто, по-моему. Однородные сказуемые: *привыкают и летают, радуются, садятся*. Союз *и* между первым и вторым. Что говорят правила на этот счет?

Comment: Думаю, связь такая: *привыкают и (летают, радуются, садятся)*, причем вторая группа связана с придаточным "если живут в доме".

Comment: Я просто не стала писать все глаголы, а поставила многоточие. Речь, конечно, идёт обо всех, а не только о первых двух. По поводу связи соглашусь с Вами.

Answer (score 0):

М**ожно предположить, что это ССП** (второе предложение неполное):

**Пойманные скворцы быстро привыкают к людям, и, если живут в доме, летают по комнатам, радуются своему хозяину,  доверчиво садятся ему на плечо.**

Связь "привыкают и летают, радуются, садятся"  мне кажется **сомнительной**, но именно она обозначена в принятом варианте.

А вот **вариант с БСП** того же содержания: Пойманные скворцы быстро привыкают к людям:  летают по комнатам, радуются своему хозяину,  доверчиво садятся ему на плечо.

Comment: На каком основании ССП? Уберите придаточное. *Пойманные скворцы быстро привыкают к людям и летают по комнатам, радуются своему хозяину, доверчиво садятся ему на плечо.* Вы хотите сказать, что и это ССП?

Comment: Я хочу сказать, что глагол "привыкают" обобщает  другие действия, а это не обозначено.  Обозначена тесная связь   - привыкают и летают,   а на каком основании? Нужно или все действия писать через запятую, или отделить "привыкают" от других действий, это более логично.

Comment: На мой взгляд, И говорит о последавательности событий: привыкают и (потом) летают, радуются, садятся

Comment: Грамматика должна точно выражать содержание, а здесь приходится "додумывать" наречия.  Я понимаю, что это учебный пример, но и учебные примеры надо составлять так, чтобы на них можно было дать однозначный ответ.